# Oracle how to instr for tab or end of line using regexp_instr

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I have the following code

```
declare
l_clob       clob;
l_line       varchar2(32767);
l_field      varchar2(32767);
l_line_start  pls_integer := 1;
l_line_end    pls_integer := 1;
l_field_start pls_integer := 1;
l_field_end   pls_integer := 1;
begin
   select response_clob
   into   l_clob
   from   xxhr.xxhr_web_service_response
   where  response_id = 290;
   -- Loop through lines.
   loop
      l_line_end := dbms_lob.instr(l_clob, chr(10), l_line_start, 1);
      l_line := dbms_lob.substr(l_clob, l_line_end - l_line_start + 1, l_line_start);
      -- If this is a line with fields and not web service garbage.
      if substr(l_line, 1, 1) = '"' then
         l_field_start := 2;
         -- Loop through fields.      
         loop
            l_field_end := instr(l_line, chr(9), l_field_start, 1);
            l_field := substr(l_line, l_field_start, l_field_end - l_field_start);  
            dbms_output.put(l_field || ',');
            l_field_start := l_field_end + 1;
            exit when l_field_end = 0;
         end loop;
         dbms_output.put_line('');         
      end if;   
      l_line_start := l_line_end + 1;
      exit when l_line_end = 0;
   end loop;
end;
```

with which I'm trying to parse this `clob` test data:

```
﻿LINE_TEXT
"PERSON_ID_NUMBER   30000   1223445454"
"PERSON_DOB 30000   01-01-1900"
```

The `clob` data is `tab` separated and has a `chr(10)` at the end. I'm not familiar with `regexp_instr`, but currently I'm only using `instr` to search for the `tab` separators; so it's missing the end of line field and producing:

```
PERSON_ID_NUMBER,30000,,
PERSON_DOB,30000,,
```

How can I change the `instr` into a `regexp_instr` to also look for the end of line character in addition to the `tab` and then correctly pick up the last field?

I need the function to be performant, since it is parsing large files.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: PERSON, 30000,,01-01-1900"

Comment: When there are easy-to-use  formats available for information transfer like CSV, JSON and so on, there's no reason why one should chose such unstructured CLOBs to read data. Not that this can't be solved but a better approach would be to sit and discuss with the owners of application /  source data and agree upon generating data in standard formats to feed into your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with:

```
declare
l_clob       clob;
l_line       varchar2(32767);
l_field      varchar2(32767);
l_line_start  pls_integer := 1;
l_line_end    pls_integer := 1;
l_field_start pls_integer := 1;
l_field_end   pls_integer := 1;
begin
   select response_clob
   into   l_clob
   from   xxhr.xxhr_web_service_response
   where  response_id = 290;
   -- Loop through lines.
   loop
      l_line_end := dbms_lob.instr(l_clob, chr(10), l_line_start, 1);
      l_line := dbms_lob.substr(l_clob, l_line_end - l_line_start + 1, l_line_start);
      -- If this is a line with fields and not web service garbage.
      if substr(l_line, 1, 1) = '"' then
         l_field_start := 2;
         -- Loop through fields.      
         loop
            l_field_end := instr(l_line, chr(9), l_field_start, 1);
            l_field := substr(l_line, l_field_start, l_field_end - l_field_start);  
            dbms_output.put(l_field || ',');
            exit when l_field_end = 0;
            l_field_start := l_field_end + 1;            
         end loop;
         l_field := substr(l_line, l_field_start);
         dbms_output.put_line(l_field);                           
      end if;   
      l_line_start := l_line_end + 1;
      exit when l_line_end = 0;
   end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the line of CLOB column by converting to `char`, and then apply `regexp_substr()` as

```
with t as
(  
select level as row_num, regexp_substr(to_char(t.line_text),'^.*$',1,level,'m') as str
  from tab t
 connect by level <= length (to_char(t.line_text)) 
                   - length (replace (to_char(t.line_text), chr (10))) + 1
)
select row_num, regexp_replace(str,'[[:space:]]+',',') as str
  from t;   

 ROW_NUM STR
 ------- -----------------------------------------
 1       PERSON_ID_NUMBER,30000,1223445454
 2       PERSON_DOB,30000,01-01-1900
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bc50611b9dab96051ed549b743181dfc)</kbd>

**Edit :** even works without `to_char()` conversion, if your CLOB is huge then you need to split step by step by `substr(str,1,4000)`, `substr(str,4001,8000)` ...

```
with t as
(
  select level as row_num, regexp_substr(substr(t.line_text,1,4000),'^.*$',1,level,'m') str
    from tab t
   connect by level <= length (substr(t.line_text,1,4000)) 
                     - length (replace(substr(t.line_text,1,4000), chr (10))) + 1 
)
select row_num, regexp_replace(substr(str,1,4000),'[[:space:]]+',',') as str
  from t
```

Comment: insert into tab
values('LINE_TEXT' || chr(10) ||
'"PERSON_ID_NUMBER   30000   1223445454"' || chr(10) ||
'"PERSON_DOB 30000   01-01-1900"' || chr(10));

Comment: Also it's in a clob because it's 37Mb.

Comment: @Superdooperhero edited the answer related to size issue. For the insert statement in the comment, what we get consider [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a3c29a8d2144a6750a57e7cbbc501cb2)

Comment: This only extracts lines, it does not extract the `tab` separated fields in the lines.